# Standby NN RPC Latency Issues

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I am currently facing an issue where i see RPC latency issues on my secondary NameNode from time to time. Log event at that instance looks like this:

```
The health test result for NAME_NODE_RPC_LATENCY has become bad: The moving average of the RPC latency is 6 second(s) over the previous 5 minute(s). The moving average of the queue time is 0 second(s). The moving average of the processing time is 6 second(s). Critical threshold: 5 second(s). 
Time: Sep 25, 2015 5:52:02 AM
```

We see these RPC errors from time to time. I looked at the logs and don't see anything different.

I checked the logs at the time the issue has occurred and found nothing unusual

```
Call#0 Retry#0: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.StandbyException: Operation category READ is not supported in state standby
```

This is usually because the client does not know where he is connecting to and as this node is standby it seamlessly connects to the active NN.

I checked the RPC avg queue time and processing time, at one point I saw that there was a burst in connections and we got an alert, however the other time when this went bad there were no burst in requests.

Any advise ? anything else I can check ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Call#0 Retry#0: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.StandbyException: Operation category READ is not supported in state standby is due to a BUG.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMBARI-13373
on similar lines. 
If you have HA enabled:
Datanodes are trying to connect to standby namenode because you might have the standby namenode in your dfs.namenode.rpc-address check hdfs-site.xml.

Workaround: Remove this property because dfs.namenode.rpc-address.DEMOMASTER.nn1 and dfs.namenode.rpc-address.DEMOMASTER.nn1 will serve the purpose of dfs.namenode.rpc-address 

How to remove?

Use the  configs.sh utility on the Ambari Server to delete the extra property.

/var/lib/ambari-server/resources/scripts/configs.sh -u
<admin.user> -p
<admin.password> delete
<ambari.server>
<cluster.name> hdfs-site “dfs.namenode.rpc-address”

Where
admin.user and
admin.password are credentials for an Ambari Administrator,
ambari.server is the Ambari Server host and
cluster.name is the name of your cluster.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes and we have HA enabled on our cluster. i will look into it. In addition what could be the reason that this latency is occurring on the standby namenode  ?